# Linq Single Column Group By not working

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'm a Linq noob so please excuse my ignorance but I need to group by a column in a table and then return just that column. I should end up with a list of unique numbers.

This is my Linq

```
from r in myTable
group r.UserID by r.UserID
```

but in Linq pad it gets close to what I want but each similar ID has a 'key' or something with all the same ids grouped together, included in the results. I just want a list of numbers.

this is the SQL that is perfect.

```
SELECT UserID FROM myTable
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not

```
var userIds = myTable.Select(r => r.UserId).Distinct();
```

or, if you prefer query syntax

```
var userIds = (from r in myTable select r.UserId).Distinct();
```

Grouping is unnecessary if you're only going to use the group ids.

Comment: +1, but `Distinct` doesn't take a projection as an argument. The syntax should be `var userIds = myTable.Select(r => r.UserId).Distinct();`. (Your query syntax version is correct.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the actual SQL you want is

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM myTable
```

Group by is doing the same thing as a side effect of your particular usage of it.

I believe the same syntax is likely functional in LINQ statement syntax, what dlev said would work though I'm not certain it gets converted to the SQL properly as it's not in the statement syntax.

If I'm mistaken and L2S will properly convert his version then by all means dlev's got it pegged.

Answer (score 0):

Your query gives you groups.  If you just want keys, you should get keys.

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<int, Record>> query1 =
  from r in myTable
  group r.UserID by r.UserID;

IQueryable<int> query2 =
  from r in myTable
  group r.UserID by r.UserID into g
  select g.Key;

  //alternatively
query1 = myTable.GroupBy(r => r.UserID);
query2 = query1.Select(g => g.Key);
```